# If $ rankA= 1$ , $A$ is positive semidefinite then $A = uv^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ positive semidefinite and  each of its entries is nonzero  and $ rankA= 1$ .

- Why does  $A = uv^T$ for non-zero vectors $u,v$?
- Now Let $A$
  be positive semidefinite can we assume $u=v$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rank $1$ means that there is at least one non-zero column, and that all columns are proportional to one another. Let $u$ be one of those columns, and let $v$ be the proportionality constant that translates between them. For instance, for the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&3&1\\
0&15&5\\
0&6&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we could use $u = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}3\\15\\6\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ (the second column) and let $v = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\1/3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ (the first column is $0$, the second is $u$ and the third is $u/3$), or we could use $u = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\5\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ together with with $v = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\3\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. You can, of course, move any non-zero factor from $u$ to $v$ to get a whole family of solutions. Note that we get exactly the same family results if we let $v^T$ be a non-zero row of the matrix, and $u$ be the proportionality constants.

So, you see, *any* rank $1$ matrix is of the form $uv^T$ for vectors $u, v$.

As for positive semidefiniteness, consider the non-zero eigenspace $U$ of $A$ (i.e. $U=\operatorname{Im}A$). That space has some eigenvalue $\lambda > 0$ attatched to it (because if $\operatorname{Im} A \subseteq \ker A$, then we won't have positive semidefiniteness, so $\lambda \neq 0$, and if $\lambda < 0$, then that's just as bad). The kernel of $A$ must be orthogonal to $V$, since $A$ is positive semidefinite. Let $u$ be a vector in $V$ of length $\sqrt{\lambda}$. That gives you $A = uu^T$.

An alternative solution to that last point: Choose $u, v$ such that $A = uv^T$. Now, if $u$ and $v$ are not parallel, then $A$ cannot be positive semidefinite. This is because in that case, there exists a vector $w$ such that $v^Tw >0$ and $w^Tu < 0$. Here is how to find such a vector:

> Take a vector $w_0$ in the orthogonal space of $u$ that is not in the orthogonal space of $v$ (such a vector exists since $u$ and $v$ are not parallel). If $v^Tw_0 <0$, pick $-w_0$ instead.
>
> Take a vector $w_1$ in the orthogonal space of $v$ that is not in the orthogonal space of $u$. If $w_1^Tu > 0$, pick $-w_1$ instead.
>
> Add these two chosen vectors to get $w$ with the property we wanted.

So we know that $u$ and $v$ must be parallel, i.e. $u = cv$ for some real scalar $c$. But we also need them to be codirectional, i.e. $c > 0$. This one is obvious, because otherwise we would have $uAu < 0$.

We now have
$$
A =uv^T =  u(cu)^T = \sqrt{c}u\left(\sqrt{c}u\right)^T = u'(u')^T
$$
for $u' = \sqrt c u$.